# Constrained optimization of sum of squares polynomials

Tags: polynomials, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, sums-of-squares

Consider the problem 
$$
\min p(x) \text{ subject to } g_j(x)\le 0
\quad
p,g_j\in\text{SOS},
\qquad
(*)
$$

i.e. $p,g_j$ ($j=1,\ldots,m$) are *sum of squares* (SOS) polynomials. Can this problem be solved efficiently?

The paper [1] shows that unconstrained minimization of SOS polynomials can be reduced to a convex program. Surprisingly, the paper goes onto consider general (non-SOS) constrained polynomial optimization to derive the Lasserre hierarchy, but never explicitly discusses the special case $(*)$ above.

[1] *Lasserre, Jean B.*, [**Global optimization with polynomials and the problem of moments**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/S1052623400366802), SIAM J. Optim. 11, No. 3, 796-817 (2001). [ZBL1010.90061](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1010.90061).

Comment: if $g_j$ is an SOS then $g_j(x)\geq 0$ for any $x$, i.e. it can be just removed from the set of constraints.

Comment: Obvious typo fixed, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: well, if $g_j$ is SOS then $g_j(x)\leq 0$ iff $g_j(x)=0$, i.e. each individual square in the SOS decomposition of $g_j$ must be 0. So it's back to Lassere's case, with equality constraints only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $g_j$ is SOS, i.e. $g_j=\sum_k h_k^2$, then $g_j(x)\leq 0$ iff $g_j(x)=0$, i.e. $h_1(x)=h_2(x)=\dots =0$. So this is a general case, although with equality constraints only.

A more interesting question would be to allow inhomogenous constraints $g_j(x)\leq b_j$, with $b_j\in\mathbb{R}$. IIRC, this would be solvable with just one step of the Lassere's hierarchy, as the whole point of it is approximating arbitrary nonnegative polynomials by SOS.
(I believe the latest Lasserre's [book](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781107447226) is discussing this in Chapter 11).